# Python - if statements involving numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm opening an image and converting it into an array of RGBA values.  Here's my code:

```
img = Image.open('17112013.png')
imgarray = array(img)
l = imgarray[:,1,1]
m = imgarray[1,:,1]
n = imgarray[1,1,:]
blueCount = 0
redCount = 0
flag = 0

for i in range(0,len(l)):
    for j in range(0,len(m)):
        if (imgarray[i,j] == [255,255,255,255]):
            pass
        if (imgarray[i,j] == [0,0,0,255] and flag == 0):
            pass
        if (imgarray[i,j] == [255,0,0,255] and flag == 0):
            pass
        if (imgarray[i,j] == [0,0,255,255]):
            flag = 1
            blueCount = blueCount + 1
        if (imgarray[i,j] == [255,0,0,255] and flag == 1):
            redCount = redCount + 1
        if (imgarray[i,j] == [0,0,0,255] and flag == 1):
            flag = 0
        if (imgarray[i,j] == [255,255,255,255] and flag == 1):
            flag = 0
```

If I run it as such, I receive the following:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I understand that I need to use these for 'if' statements containing numpy arrays; however, I am unsure of the correct syntax to implement this. Probably just being stupid, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A search SO for `[numpy] ambiguous` turns up many questions about this error message.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
if np.all(imgarray[i,j] == [255,255,255,255]):
```

If that particular slice of `imgarray` is indeed `[255,255,255,255]`, then the equality comparison will return `array([ True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)`. You can't expect `if` to know what to do with this boolean array directly, as you have discovered, but the function `numpy.all(x)` returns `True` if all of the values in array `x` are equivalent to `True` and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, when using  `if` with an array of logical value is not clear what you want. I'm assuming that you only want true if every part of the current `imgarray[i,j]` is equal to the compared array. You also better to use excessive brackets and the logical `&` operator to be explicit about what you want. This runs,

```
import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('17112013.png')
imgarray = np.array(img)
l = imgarray[:,1,1]
m = imgarray[1,:,1]
n = imgarray[1,1,:]
blueCount = 0
redCount = 0
flag = 0

for i in range(0,len(l)):
    for j in range(0,len(m)):
        if (np.all(imgarray[i,j] == [255,255,255,255])):
            pass
        if (np.all(imgarray[i,j] == [0,0,0,255]) & flag == 0):
            pass
        if (np.all(imgarray[i,j] == [255,0,0,255]) & flag == 0):
            pass
        if (np.all(imgarray[i,j] == [0,0,255,255])):
            flag = 1
            blueCount = blueCount + 1
        if (np.all(imgarray[i,j] == [255,0,0,255]) & flag == 1):
            redCount = redCount + 1
        if (np.all(imgarray[i,j] == [0,0,0,255]) & flag == 1):
            flag = 0
        if (np.all(imgarray[i,j] == [255,255,255,255]) & flag == 1):
            flag = 0
```

Not sure if it is what you need?